# Securing weservice with SymmetricBinding policy

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf

is there anybody who can help me configure STS server to work with SymmetricBinding Policy?

I have following service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http" xmlns:x1="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:t="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="HelloWorld" targetNamespace="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types" targetNamespace="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <simpleType name="MyStringType">
                <restriction base="string">
                    <maxLength value="30"/>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
            <element name="greetMe">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="requestType" type="tns:MyStringType"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="greetMeResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="responseType" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="greetMeRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="x1:greetMe" name="in"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="greetMeResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="x1:greetMeResponse" name="out"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Greeter">
        <wsdl:operation name="greetMe">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:greetMeRequest" name="greetMeRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:greetMeResponse" name="greetMeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="Greeter_SOAPBinding" type="tns:Greeter">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#AsymmetricSAML2Policy"/>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="greetMe">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="greetMeRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Input_Policy"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="greetMeResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Output_Policy"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SOAPService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:Greeter_SOAPBinding" name="SoapPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9001/SoapContext/SoapPort"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="AsymmetricSAML2Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false">
                    <wsp:Policy/>
                </wsam:Addressing>
                <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:InitiatorToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:IssuedToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                                        <t:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</t:TokenType>
                                        <t:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/PublicKey</t:KeyType>
                                    </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:RequireInternalReference/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Issuer>
                                        <wsaw:Address>http://127.0.0.1:8080/SecurityTokenService
                                                                                </wsaw:Address>
                                    </sp:Issuer>
                                </sp:IssuedToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <sp:RecipientToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                        <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:RecipientToken>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Lax/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <sp:Wss11>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Wss11>
                <sp:Trust13>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
                        <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
                        <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Trust13>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Input_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Output_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and I use CXF to create STS server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd         
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
    <bean id="utSTSProviderBean" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.sts.provider.SecurityTokenServiceProvider">
        <property name="issueOperation" ref="utIssueDelegate"/>
        <property name="validateOperation" ref="utValidateDelegate"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="utIssueDelegate" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.operation.TokenIssueOperation">
        <property name="tokenProviders" ref="utSamlTokenProvider"/>
        <property name="services" ref="utService"/>
        <property name="stsProperties" ref="utSTSProperties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="utValidateDelegate" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.operation.TokenValidateOperation">
        <property name="tokenValidators" ref="utSamlTokenValidator"/>
        <property name="stsProperties" ref="utSTSProperties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="utSamlTokenProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.token.provider.SAMLTokenProvider">
    </bean>
    <bean id="utSamlTokenValidator" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.token.validator.SAMLTokenValidator">
    </bean>
    <bean id="utService" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.service.StaticService">
        <property name="endpoints" ref="utEndpoints"/>
    </bean>
    <util:list id="utEndpoints">
        <value>http://${sts.host}:(\d)*/SoapContext/SoapPort</value>
    </util:list>
    <bean id="utSTSProperties" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.StaticSTSProperties">
        <property name="signaturePropertiesFile" value="stsKeystore.properties"/>
        <property name="signatureUsername" value="mystskey"/>
        <property name="callbackHandlerClass" value="pl.invicta.STSCallbackHandler"/>
        <property name="issuer" value="MySTSIssuer"/>
    </bean>
    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/" id="UTSTS"
                    implementor="#utSTSProviderBean" address="http://${sts.host}:${sts.port}/SecurityTokenService/UT"
                    wsdlLocation="wsdl/ws-trust-1.4-service.wsdl" serviceName="ns1:SecurityTokenService"
                    endpointName="ns1:UT_Port">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="pl.invicta.STSCallbackHandler"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="stsKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.username" value="mystskey"/>
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

For such configuration all processing works well, but when I change binding to symmetric as:

```
<sp:SymmetricBinding>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:ProtectionToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:IssuedToken
                                        sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                                        <t:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</t:TokenType>
                                        <t:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</t:KeyType>
                                        <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
                                    </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:RequireInternalReference/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Issuer>
                                        <wsaw:Address>http://127.0.0.1:8080/SecurityTokenService</wsaw:Address>
                                        <wsaw:Metadata>
                                            <wsx:Metadata>
                                                <wsx:MetadataSection>
                                                    <wsx:MetadataReference>
                                                        <wsaw:Address>http://127.0.0.1:8080/SecurityTokenService
                                                        </wsaw:Address>
                                                    </wsx:MetadataReference>
                                                </wsx:MetadataSection>
                                            </wsx:Metadata>
                                        </wsaw:Metadata>
                                    </sp:Issuer>
                                </sp:IssuedToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:ProtectionToken>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Lax/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SymmetricBinding>
```

I receive error:

```
2017-04-24 14:02:47.414 {- WARN} [qtp766232641-16] o.a.c.s.t.provider.SAMLTokenProvider     : 
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.sts.provider.STSException: The specified request failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable debug logging on the STS it will tell you what the problem is. There are loads of Symmetric tests for the STS in the CXF source: e.g. https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/services/sts/systests/basic/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/sts/symmetric/SymmetricBindingTest.java